# Difference between decimal.Round and Math.Round

Tags: c#

What is the difference between Math.Round and decimal.Round functions in C# ?

Comment: There is no difference. `Math.Round(decimal)` calls `Decimal.Round(decimal)` http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,85130852558b2bc9

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no difference.

`Math.Round(decimal)` source code:

```
public static Decimal Round(Decimal d) {
        return Decimal.Round(d,0);
}
```

[Reference Source .NET Framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,155)

To clarify, source code for `decimal.cs` class:

```
public static Decimal Round(Decimal d) {
        return Round(d, 0);
}
```

Comment: There is a difference in that the number of sig digs is set to 0 for `Math.Round`

Comment: @Haney only if you do not provide the number of digits to round to. `decimal.Round(Decimal d)` does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes , answer wise no difference but passing the value is different 
**Math.Round** accept double and float but decimal.Round accept only **decimal struct**.

Comment: I don't know if this ever was correct, but it's not now. Math.Round() has overloads for decimal type.